# How to apply word wrap in li text without adjusting width?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

Is there a way to wrap the text inside li without adjusting its width ?

For example, in the below structure -

```
<ul>
    <li>Sample Text</li>
    <li>Sample Text</li>
    <li>Sample Text</li>
    <li>Sample Text</li>
</ul>
```

I want to wrap the text after Sample. How can I achieve this ?

Comment: `<li>Sample<br>Text</li>`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Set [`word-spacing`](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_text_word-spacing.asp) to a low value so it's always wrapped
2. Set [`width`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/width) to `min-content`

```css
li {
    word-spacing: 1px; 
    
    width: min-content;
    width: -webkit-min-content;
    width: -moz-min-content;
}
```

```html
<ul>
    <li>Sample Text</li>
    <li>Sample Text</li>
    <li>Sample Text</li>
    <li>Sample Text</li>
</ul>
```

---

A pure html solution would be applying a [`<br>`](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_br.asp) between the words;

```html
<ul>
    <li>Sample<br>Text</li>
    <li>Sample<br>Text</li>
    <li>Sample<br>Text</li>
    <li>Sample<br>Text</li>
</ul>
```